# Why is "Arithmetic Coding" named as such?

Tags: compression, information-theory

I've been reviewing the algorithm for arithmetic coding, and I can't seem to work out why it was given the name "arithmetic coding". Can anybody shed any light?

Answer (score 3):

Because it is using arithmetic, coding the message into a giant fraction. This is as opposed to Huffman which codes each symbol as a series of bits.

From the abstract of the original paper:

> Algorithms for encoding and decoding finite strings over a finite
>   alphabet are described. The coding operations are arithmetic involving
>   rational numbers ...